# command_not_found_handler does not with with slashes

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem with `"/"` sign in bash shell (version 4.3 in Ubuntu 16). I have a function:

```
command_not_found_handler() {
  if [[ "$1" =~ any$ ]]; then
    echo "$1"
  fi
}
```

This function should write back the contents of any command written in the terminal when this command ends with `any`.

This works well, except in the situation when I write something with a `/`, such as `whatever/any`. In that event, I receive an error akin to the following:

```
bash: no such file or directory: whatever/any
```

Any attempts to escape this `/` in the function have no effect (for instance `if [[ "$1" =~ /any$ ]]; then` or `if [[ "$1" =~ \/any$ ]]; then`).

What can I do to make it work with `/` sign?

Comment: That's not a limitation with slashes in general, or with `[[ ]]`, it's a limitation with how the command_not_found_handler function works.

Comment: Can you not remove slash from $1 before if condition?

Comment: @dganesh2002, the function isn't called at all if there's a /, so it's rather moot.

Comment: Is this an isolated example? I mean: shebang over the code, function call below it, or does this happen within a bigger script? I'm unable to reproduce it.

Comment: @alagner, `command_not_found_handle` is interactive-shell functionality, so no shebang needed and no explicit call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`command_not_found_handle` (no trailing `r`) is only invoked after doing a search through the PATH for a given command.

No such search occurs when the user is passing an explicit path to a command, which is how anything containing a `/` is interpreted.

---

To quote [the relevant documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html), with emphasis added:

> 3. If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, **and contains no slashes**, Bash searches each element of `$PATH` for a directory containing an executable file by that name. Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files to avoid multiple `PATH` searches (see the description of hash in [Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)). A full search of the directories in `$PATH` is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table. If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell function named `command_not_found_handle`. If that function exists, it is invoked with the original command and the original command’s arguments as its arguments, and the function’s exit status becomes the exit status of the shell. If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error message and returns an exit status of 127.

The entire paragraph of documentation is relevant only in the set of conditions set out at the beginning: A command must not be a shell function, must not be a builtin, and must not contain slashes.